# Canvas context.fillText() vs context.strokeText()

Tags: html, canvas

Is there any difference between `context.fillText()` and `context.strokeText()` besides the fact that the first uses `context.fillStyle` while the later uses `context.strokeStyle`. Any reason they did not add a `context.textStyle` property?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green'
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.font = '90px verdana';
ctx.fillText('Q', 50, 100);
ctx.strokeText('Q', 125, 100);
ctx.fillText('Q', 200, 100);
ctx.strokeText('Q', 200, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Yep, strokeText actually strokes the outline of the letters while fillText fills the inside of the letters.

[image]

Comment: ah cool, I guess I was just creating texts too small to notice the strokeText property. Thanks.

Comment: 4 times `Q` is called in given code but 3Q is in image?

Comment: @diEcho The 3rd and 4th calls draw to the same Q, one for its fill, one for the stroke.